# Basic VLAN setup help needed, HPV1910 Switch->SonicWALL 3600

Tags: vlan

I'm struggling to get a basic VLAN working across my equipment an HP V1910 switch and a SonicWall 3600 router.

Here is what I have:

**HP V1910**

VLAN 1 - Mgmt 192.168.10.x

VLAN 20 - Wireless 191.168.20.x

The following VLAN interfaces are defined on the HPV1910

VLAN 1 192.168.10.188

VLAN 20 192.168.20.188

Port #4 is my trunk to the Sonicwall

Port #4 is setup as: VLAN 1 [untagged], VLAN 20 [tagged], PVID 1, Link Type Trunk

Port #23 is my testing port. I have a Windows 7 machine plugged into it with a static IP of 192.168.20.150

Port #23 is setup as: VLAN 20 [tagged], VLAN 20

What I want to happen is that the Win7 box on Port 23 gets VLAN 20 assigned via port #23's PVID, and that traffic then sent to the SonicWall via port #4's trunk.

Some pictures of the HP setups:

[HP Port 23 Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evetL.png)

[HP VLAN 20 Port Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzSDL.png)

**SonicWall 3600**

My interfaces on the SonicWall are as follows:

X0 - Zone LAN    192.168.10.199

X1 - Zone WAN    --our public ip--

X7:V20 - Zone WIFI-LAN    192.168.20.199

The WIFI-LAN zone is setup as a trusted interface.  Because of this the SonicWall auto-added routing between the LAN and the WIFI-LAN zones.

What do I set as the gateway on the Windows 7 computer? The Win7 box cannot ping the vlan interface 192.168.20.199 on the Sonicwall or any other machine on the .10 subnet.

Any thoughts on where I have this setup wrong, or what information I can provide to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a little bit confusion.
I don't use HP switch but on cisco will work in this way:

```
port 23 vlan20 untagged (pc port for internet browsing)
port 4 vlan20 tagged and vlan1 untagged
port 22 vlan1 untagged
```

So if you want to be ready for browsing you need to use port 23, for management you'll need to plug into 22 port.
Otherwise it will be important to know if your sonic-wall (but i think so) can use 2 different vlans networks configuring 802.1q on the same interface.
Of course you need to jump on interface 22 for Sysadmin configuration (and setting the right ip) and on interface 23 for browsing internet (setting the right ip)
I hope it helps!